# Can see the value of the variable but can't use it to validate PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
function number_of_fb_comments()
{
    return $number = "<fb:comments-count href=" . get_permalink($post->ID) . " ></fb:comments-count>";
}
?>
<?php
function get_fb_comments()
{
    $number = number_of_fb_comments();

    if ($number == 1) {

        echo "<a href =$url#facebook_comments > $number Comment</a></span>";

    } else if ($number > 1) {

        echo "<a href =$url#facebook_comments > $number Comments</a></span>"; 

    } else {

        echo "<a href=$url#facebook_comments>Leave a comment</a> </span>";

    }
} ?>
```

I'm trying to make a validation of my facebook comments, but I can't seem to use the '$number' to validate it in the if statement, but I can echo the value and see it.

So it will only goes to the 'else' part....

I have made $number as a global variable and after using var_dumb($number)

I'm seeing series of out put on each of the post

```
 string(104) "0" 
 string(118) "1"
 string(111) "0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$number` you're calling returns a string (`return $number = "<fb:comments-count href="`), which is not `1` or `>1` - it appears you'll want to return some different data from your `number_of_fb_comments()` function.

Comment: I've figured about that, and tried this and it doesn't work still? `    $number = (int)$number;` ???

Comment: Also when I echo it out I can actually see the number though... I meant like 0,1,2,3,4 depends on the post comment count. except I can't validate it.

Comment: Try  a var_dump on that variable to see what the output is. Also, if $post isn't global I don't see how your function is referencing that variable.

Comment: I can see it as it is an assignment from a function call that is why 
`$number = number_of_fb_comments();`

Comment: See the length of the var_dump's? 104, 118, and 111. Take a look at the source of the page in your browser, it will have the html in there, which is what is causing it to not match 1 or > 1

Comment: wow I just saw that it is not displaying the number in the source code.... :( is there anyway to get the number that is being display?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Facebook API off hand. I'd probably open a new question for that one!

Comment: it is okay... thank you so much I guess I have to go back and use the fopen again.